# Latin for clockwise/anticlockwise?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm trying to express 'clockwise' and 'anti-clockwise' in Latin, for which there are not likely to be classical precedents.

Other languages generally seem to lack such brief and simple expressions : in German and French, for example, it's necessary to employ phrases using the movement of a clock's hands, which in comparison with the English feel long and clumsy.  In Russian it's a little neater, по часовой стрелке 'arrow of time', comparable with *modo solarii*, 'in the same way as the sundial'.

I suppose *modo solarii* works after a fashion, but it's somehow unsatisfying. Can anyone suggest something better?

Comment: I'm not an expert at Latin in any way and by all means I don't even study, speak or read or anything. I only landed here because I found the question interesting. Anyways... I could believe there is no such equivalent to the expressions because they didn't have clocks like we do. Maybe?!?! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Dextro**(ve)**rsum**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddextrorsum) for *clockwise* and [**sinistro**(ve)**rsum**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DS%3Aentry%20group%3D46%3Aentry%3Dsinistrorsus) for *counter/anticlockwise* are accepted in a number of scientific fields (e.g. [physics](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&index=frb&srchtxt=DEXTRORSUM), [botanic](http://www.mobot.org/mobot/latindict/keyDetail.aspx?keyWord=dextrorsum).) Their respective meaning, *stricto sensu*, is to the right (or left.)

The association between *to the right* and a *clockwise* movement seems old and hard to document. Present day explanations include a natural trend to observe the [movement from the top](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404295/why-does-right-mean-clockwise/404591#404591) and the fact that [clocks descend from sundials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwise), which in the northern hemisphere cast shadows that move both to the right and clockwise.

Comment: Thank you. This is entirely in sympathy with English terms such as _right-hand thread_ and suits my purpose exactly.

Comment: Are there any corresponding adjective expressions? or I have to use a participle like **movens** along?

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian not that I know (which doesn't mean a definitive 'no'). But you can use a phrase like [_ad dexteram vertens_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dverto) or _maybe_ _dextrovertens_ (knowing that it is probably unatested).

Answer (score 11):

In [botanical Latin](http://www.cambridge.org/br/academic/subjects/life-sciences/botanical-reference/primer-botanical-latin-vocabulary?format=PB&isbn=9781107693753#qD7hAqghe7MQ7Y7m.97), the following terms are used:

- helicte - clockwise
- antihelicte - counter-clockwise

Comment: These are good suggestions, and very tempting, but too close to the English _helical_, with an underlying implication that does not suit my present problem. Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I believe 'sinister' and 'dexter' may be viable choices.

- http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/35129/sinister-sinistra
- http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/17327/dexter-dextera
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinistral_and_dextral